# How to get character from number of buttons that buttons added in GridView using Tag and position in Android

Tags: java, android

Buttons added in GridView programmatically the total number of buttons depend on word length. Each button contains a letter of word, i want to get that letter when click the button using tag,
how can i get?
here is the code:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) 
    {  
         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         v = vi.inflate(R.layout.buttonlist, null);
    } 

    final Button btn= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.letterbtn);
    btn.setText(word[position]+"");
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            btn.setTag(btn);
            Object tag=btn.getTag();

            btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            function(position); 
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
  String tag=btn.getTag().toString(); 
               or
  String tag=(String)btn.getTag();
```

instead of

```
  Object tag=btn.getTag();
```

hope it will help you. And basically you can use `getText()` method instead of tag which returns text from view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. another one question how to get the position of button in GridView using this tag?

Comment: What position. Do you want to know where the button is located. or how many buttons are there before this button/view

Comment: I have got tag. Using that tag i want to know position, where the button is located in GridView

Comment: Why don't you set some tag, and after getting that tag, you can have a switch case and return a position accordingly. Better you post another question on SO. with code how and what you are setting tag